Flink task manager does not unload classes
I have Standalone Flink Cluster. When I stop the process on Task Manager, classes that were loaded as ChildFirst are not removed. After several start/stop repetitions, the metaspace exceeds the maximum value and throws OutOfMemory Metaspace.
I run servals application in one task manager. Application are different so a cannot add the JAR file to /lib folder. Restarting TaskManager after severals operation is bothersome.


Flink 1.20.0
Java 17.0.11+9
I tried change the class loader order to parent-first as the suggest in doc https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.20/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/ but this not helped. Even then, the classes are loaded as Child First.
EDIT
I found that MySQL is the problem



Are you using HFS (Hadoop file system)?

no, i do not. I have seen this issue on HSF

The thread for cleaning abandoned connections is created in the JVM as static, so the GC can't do anything with it, which ultimately blocked unloading classes. In driver version 8.x, you can disable the creation of this thread by adding to the JVM parameter
-Dcom.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup=true

In Flink you can add this to config.yaml file like this:
env:
   java:
      opts:
         all: -Dcom.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup=true

In older versions of the driver, there is no such option and the only thing you can do is to disable this thread manually at the application startup by executing com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();

Flink has had issues with hanging on to classes. These were both related to Hadoop, but maybe something similar is happening in your situation. You can check for a pending shutdown hook with code like this:
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks");
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("hooks");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Map<Thread, Thread> hooks = (Map<Thread, Thread>) field.get(null);
            for (Thread hook : hooks.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(hook.getClass().getName());
            }

You could also check for active threads, as that's another way for code to not get unloaded.

I finally found what is problem. MySQL driver has thread name mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup which is not close after stop job in task manager.
MySQL driver lib is in flink lib already and this did not helped.
Any advice how to deal with it?

I shutdown this thread via driver
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.uncheckedShutdown()
then GC properly cleaning data but is this only solution?

It can also be done by set in config.yaml parameter to JVM
-Dcom.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup=true

Hi Michał - congrats on figuring it out! I would suggest you answer your own question with the config.yaml solution, as that seems like the right approach. That way other users can more easily benefit from your research.
